# Remote Desktop black screen

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vps, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

Today, when I went to remote to my VPS (with Windows 2012 r2), remote desktop shows me black screen and closed after some seconds. I've tested remote from other client (with different OS) but again shows black screen and closes.
I checked all solutions for this problem in the net but none work in my case. Some solutions that I've checked:

- remove some windows updates
- check user access
- add user to Interactive and Authenticated Users group
- test with other user account
- uninstall Anti Virus
- change some configuration in remote desktop application
- reinstall graphic card driver
- commands: `netsh int tcp set global rss=disabled` and `netsh int tcp set
  global chimney=disabled`
- check RD Gateway SSL certificate
- http://www.grishbi.com/2015/01/rdp-black-screen/

When i check remote desktop event log, I'm found this error:

`The RDP protocol component X.224 detected an error(0) in protocol stream and the client disconnected`
with Event Id `97`
what this Event Id means and how can remote my VPS with remote desktop?
(of Course i can access to VPS with VNC)

Edit:
Also I found this event in Event Viewer:
`The Desktop Window Manager has exited with code (0xd00002fe)`    Event Id:9009

Comment: Give the command `netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled` a shot on the server to see if that resolves. See [Using Netsh Commands to Enable or Disable TCP Chimney Offload](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg162682(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: thanks, i test it now but doesn't work(can't remote)

Comment: Actually try both `netsh int tcp set global rss=disabled` and `netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled`. Here's the article [Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951037) even though it's Server 2008 I'd give it a shot just in case. See here for all including Server 2012 for more detail of what this is [TCP Offloading/Chimney & RSS…What is it and should I disable it?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/onthewire/archive/2014/01/21/tcp-offloading-chimney-amp-rss-what-is-it-and-should-i-disable-it.aspx).

Comment: Last comment too or else I'll add it all as an answer, see here as well --> [Microsoft Blog - In Case you use Certificates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2011/01/10/how-to-resolve-the-issue-remote-desktop-disconnected-or-unable-to-connect-to-remote-desktop-terminal-server.aspx)

Comment: `netsh int tcp set global rss=disabled` and `netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled` doesn't work in my case!!! I'm working on `Microsoft Blog - In Case you use Certificates`

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Curious of the solution if so?

Comment: I can't find any solution! also I create a post in Microsoft TechNet , but all of answers didn't work in my case.

Comment: Can you comment back a link to the TechNet post when you get a chance so I can review what all you've tried?

Comment: Ok, see this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87393e12-7e1f-4836-9729-21901cf4c80d/remote-desktop-show-black-screen-and-closed?forum=winserverTS